# Is it necessary to include data encoded in a token to the returned response?

Tags: json, python-3.x, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

This is a general question. 
I am using JWT for my user's authentication and in the JWT I encode the

1. username
2. email

Now after a user login successfully, I return a response in the following format

```
{
  "user": {
    "email": "john@doe.jake",
    "username": "johndoe",
    "token": "jwt.token.here",
  }
}
```

I see like I am just repeating myself by including the `email` and `username` in the response given that they exist in the token. 
What is the best practice in such a case?

Comment: If you don't include this information in response, In UI side, the developer should base64decode and then fetch email data from it. I don't think it's a hard task to do for UI developers or any App developer. On the other side, It's not so bad to include extra data beside response of jwt token.

Comment: I believe there is not exact response for this question. It's all based on situation and your team and design of your team coding. But in general response, payload of jwt is for this kind of stuff. put every data for front users in payload. But there is not exact face to not to do it like what you did